# Spark with MSSQL - Connection object and JDBCRDD

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark

I would want an application that -

1. Reads data from MSSQL Server
2. Puts this data into spark
3. Performs computations using RDD
4. Writes data into another database using JDBCRDD

My question is that in point no. 4 regarding writing the data into another database using JDBCRDD, when creating JDBCRDD we specify the connection parameter.

When we create JDBCRDD and it is distributed over cluster nodes, how is the connection object distributed?
Is it distributed or multiple connection objects are created for each partition/node in spark setup?

Comment: So the first paragraph of your question is totally irrelevant for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a function or factory which gives a connection object, then it will be one per partition.
If you have just use just one connection with JDBCRDD then it will one shared connection for all the partitions.

Relevant code from Spark [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.scala#L73)